# PETSc with shared memory

Tags: mpi, shared-memory, petsc

I have an MPI parallel code using PETSc to solve a linear equation system with a matrix-free GMRES method. It works fine, but each process uses about the same amount of memory, independent of the number of processes I use. So when using many processes, memory usage gets excessive. I am wondering if there is a way around this and I think using a shared memory approach might be the way to go.

As I understand the [PETSc website](https://www.mcs.anl.gov/petsc/miscellaneous/petscthreads.html) shared memory is supported by PETSc (MPI shared memory is used for simplicity), but I can't find any information on how to enable or use it. Is using PETSc with shared memory a possible solution to my problem and if yes, is there any documentation on how to do this? Or is MPI shared memory used in PETSc by default if possible without any need for additional coding?

Comment: There is not a single mention of any MPI shared-memory window routines in the source code of the latest PETSc release (v3.7.3). There is some code that implements shared-memory vectors using System V IPC calls, but the code is incomplete and leaves the IPC objects behind. Running such code will probably make your system administrators very unhappy.

Comment: Thanks, if you make this an answer I'll try and accept it before the question gets downvoted too much ;)

Comment: I'm not really a PETSc user. I just performed a grep over the source tree. Perhaps, some real PETSc user could provide a real answer.

Comment: The fact that each process uses about the same amount of memory just means that the problem has been distributed between the processes in a balanced way (at least for memory), which is a good thing. An important increase of the overall memory requirement may be due to a large number of [ghost nodes](http://www.tecplot.com/blog/faqs/ghost-nodes-ghost-cells/). In a finite difference code, this can be due to a large stencil. For methods using adaptative meshes, the problem can be due to the [partitioning](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~quake/sc96/node5.html) step.

Comment: I may not have been clear when saying "each process uses about the same amount of memory". What I mean is that memory usage per process is independent of the number of processes, so say I need 1GB using 1 proc I will need 4GB on 4 procs for the same problem.

Comment: Also, I am not using a mesh with ghost cells. What I do is a Fast Multipole Boundary Element Method in which every process potentially needs to access data from all over the computational domain. So it kind of does make sense that the data is multiplied in a distributed memory approach - that's why I'm looking for something with shared memory.